# C++ random 0xC0000005 errors

Tags: c++

I made a program which converts **n** decimal numbers **sk**   into other numerical system **p** but sometimes it crashes and the error code I get is 0xC0000005 (program still converts and outputs all the numbers) . One thing I just noticed that it happens then converted number is longer than 6 symbols (or it's just a coincidence).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long n,sk,p,j;
    string liekanos;
    ifstream f("u1.txt");
    f >> n;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        f >> sk >> p;
        j=0;
        while (sk>0)
        {
            liekanos[j]=sk % p;
            sk/=p;
            j++;
        }
        for (j>=0;j--;)
        {
            if (liekanos[j]<10)
                cout<<int(liekanos[j]);
            else cout<<char(liekanos[j]+55);
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example input:

```
3
976421618 7
15835 24
2147483647 2
```

Comment: Just so you know, `0xC0000005` is an access violation (bad pointer) error.  It generally means the pointer handling or memory allocation in the program is flawed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `liekanos[j]` you access element at index `j` but since you haven't specify size of this string, you are most likely trying to access non-existing element. You could call `liekanos.resize(sk)` before you enter your `while` loop to make sure it never happens.

Or if you know the maximum possible size of `liekanos`, you could declare it as `string liekanos(N, c);` where `N` is its size and `c` is the default value of each character in it.

Comment: `std::string` has resize too. Why not just keep it as a `std::string`?

Comment: @Marlon: My point is, that it is declared as a `string` but never used as one.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting undefined behavior because your `liekanos` string never has any size or capacity.

Answer (score 1):

```
string liekanos;
```

By default string has zero size. But you try to

```
liekanos[j]=sk % p;
```

Answer (score -1):

Better use `std::vector<char> liekanos;` instead of `string liekanos;`.
You'll need to do some modifications in your code:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    std::vector<char> liekanos;
    f >> sk >> p;
    while (sk>0)
    {
        liekanos.push_back(sk % p);
        sk/=p;
    }
    for (long j = liekanos.size(); j>=0; --j)
    {
        if (liekanos[j]<10)
            cout<<int(liekanos[j]);
        else cout<<char(liekanos[j]+'a');
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: For what reason would a vector be better?

Comment: @Zyx2000 I think the `std::vector<char>` here is more intuitive than `std::string` as we're processing one character at a time and getting a collection of characters. 
From the performance point of view I think both solutions will be equal. `std::string` may be better if we'll need to do some operations such as concatenating two representations.