# Not getting any output for string

Tags: c++, string

I'm not getting any output for str2. Why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {   
    string str1,str2;
    int t_cases,i,j,length;

    cin>>t_cases;

    for (i=0;i<t_cases;i++)
    {
        cin>>str1;
        length=str1.length();

        for (j=0;j<length;j++)
            str2[j]=str1[length-1-j];

        cout<<str2<<endl;;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, logically indent your code.

Comment: What value did you choose for t_cases?

Comment: What did you try ? have you add some debug ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ random 0xC0000005 errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570818/c-random-0xc0000005-errors)

Answer (score 8):

`str2` is empty, buy you access it as if it had non-zero size here:

```
str2[j]=str1[length-1-j];
```

This is *undefined behaviour*.

You could initialize `str2` to be of the right size from the outset (inside the first loop):

```
for (i=0;i<t_cases;i++)
{
    cin>>str1;
    length=str1.length();
    std::string str2(length, ' '); // string with t_cases spaces
```

or default construct it, and append to it as suggested by @saviourself (also inside the first loop):

```
for (i=0;i<t_cases;i++)
{
    cin>>str1;
    length=str1.length();
    std::string str2
    for (j=0;j<length;j++)
        str2 += str1[length-1-j];
```

Comment: If he changes `str2[j] = str1[length - 1 - j];` to `str2 += str1[length - 1 - j];` he'll be fine.

Comment: Actually, he'd have to reset str2 as well. He would also have to move the initialization of str2 inside of the for loop for this to run bug free, otherwise he'd constantly be appending to the second string.

Answer (score 3):

str2 is empty, just add

```
 str2.resize(length);
```

and It should work

Because what you are doing is unsafe:

> If pos is not greater than the string length, the function never
>   throws exceptions (no-throw guarantee). Otherwise, it causes undefined
>   behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking undefined behaviour. str2 is of 0 length and you are trying to write data after the end. If you use `str.at(j)` it will abort.

Resize str2 or append the new values.