# Process returned -1073741819 when trying to return 0

Tags: c

I'm programming in C using Code::Blocks, my program compiles properly but crashes when executing, giving the apparently very famous "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)".

I've searched evrywhere and it seems to me that my problem is different from what I've found elsewhere (just for you to know that I've trying looking for the answer for a long time before coming here).

I use *calloc* several times in my code, but it doesn't seem to be the problem : after trying to find the source of the problem it seems like my program bugs when trying to "return 0;" at the very end !

When I try to *free* everything I've allocated dynamically (what I hadn't done in the first place) the program now crashes at this point.

Have you got some intuitions about what could be the source of the problem ?

My program is 500 lines long and pretty messy for now so I don't put it there right now, but if you want, I can !
I'm a beginner in C so it is possible I completly missed something, thank you for not being to harsh with me =)

/// edit : found the solution///

Okay I think I understand why my code crashed like that (although I don't get why it crashed so late in the program, I think it should have earlier ...).

It was a problem in the construction of the arrays allocated dynamically.

For those interested,you had to get the structure of the program to get the problem (Which is pretty ugly considering it's not ended and has not enough comments to be readable...) there are two big loops in my program (126->180 and 283->388); one to get the size of the several arrays I allocate dynamically, the second to fill them. These loops are supposed to be almost the same. However I forgot half of the loop in the first one... So the size was incorrect (too small) and I filled with the correct number of integers...

Now it works fine. Thanks for having helped me, I asked myself the good questions thanks to you =) (though I still don't get why the error was at the very end ...)

Comment: are we talking C or C++ here? anyway, you are probably freeing something you already freed before. I suggest you free each block separately and finding the bad one. Also look up valgrind and debugging with watch break points.

Comment: Why don't you comment out most of allocations and free and see which one exactly causes the problem?

Comment: @NiRR, look at the question tag

Comment: hi pierre; would you mind posting some of your code?
and for the wildshot: "maybe you return a variable before 'return 0;'"?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to free some already deallocated memory. Its difficult to say without looking at the code. Use http://codepad.org/ to share the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ random 0xC0000005 errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570818/c-random-0xc0000005-errors)

Comment: NiRR : I'm talking C here, and I don't think I tried freeing something already freed. But I'll try isolating each block.

Comment: fayyazkl : Finally what bothers me most is that even the "return" crashes ... I'd expect that of a "free" as it's possible I was not rigorous enough when coding, but the return was king of a sure thing for me until now...

Comment: Zaibordg : here is my code http://codepad.org/kvytPB9Y it's not easily readable (sorry for the comments in French by the way ...) but the important is the end (the last 5 lines), the lines from 74 to 86 and from 185 to 236 where I use calloc several times.

Comment: Kunal : I don't think I freed already deallocated memory, or maybe there are some case where it is deallocated automatically ?

And for everybody : don't pay attention to the "free(genTerm);" in comment at the end of the code, but you can see that if you make the other "free" appear, the code crashes there.

Thank you all for your answers !

Comment: Oh and at the beggining you just have to type 12, then 1, then 15.

Answer (score 4):

`0xC0000005` is the error code for `Memory Access Violation`. In other words, you have a `SEGFAULT` which usually happens when you're trying to access a dereferenced zone of memory or when you're trying to deallocate twice the same object.

Fortunately Code::Blocks is shipped with a debugger when you can pinpoint exactly which instruction cause the memory access violation.

Comment: But isn't it weird then that the problem occurs only when trying to return 0;
(here is the code if you like : http://codepad.org/kvytPB9Y it's a bit dense but at the end I put 2 "printf", one before and one after the return, and it seems like the problem is really here..)


However when adding the "free" it could be a problem of allocation.
I'll try with the debugger (eventhough I don't know how to use it, I'll learn =) )
Thank you !

Comment: The 'return 0;' is the exit point of the program : you can't put whatever you want after, it will not be evaluated. I've looked into your code, and it works fine on my computer.

Comment: Hum yes it was not a good idea to add a printf after the return, sorry.
But it's weird it works fine on your computer and not mine though... Does it work even when adding the "free" that were here only in comment ? (except for the free(genTerm), that was already freed)